# Hosting ASP.NET application using Port other than 80 and 443

Tags: asp.net, iis, web-hosting, windows-server-2012-r2

If I host a website on a windows server on port 8080, Can I access it without a port number? application is accessible if I use Server IP:8080 but I would like to access it without port and without hosting it on port 80/443

I know if I host it on port 80 or 443 (SSL) it will be accessible without port but I have a requirement not to use the default port for hosting the application.

Once the above is accomplish next step would be to make it available publicly, I already have the public IP and even did NAT configuration using port 8080 but as mentioned above requirement is not to use default port.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

On a public website the answer is no.

A web browser will not connect to a non-standard port without the protocol(HTTP or HTTPS) and the port (:8080) after the dns name.

You can do this using a link.

If you could open port 80, you could use redirection to the server on port 8080.

It is also possible to register a protocol handler on the clients to allow a client to look for port 8080. You must own the computers for this to be a viable option.

Comment: Thanks for the response, if I host it on port 8080 then I will have to use domain:8080 or If I choose to host on port 80 then I can access it via only the domain name, right?

Answer (score 0):

If you want to change the standard port for your internal networks, then you need to configure the port binding in IIS configuration

[image]

Here is complete guide:
https://knowledge.digicert.com/solution/SO9987.html

If you want to change standard port for your public access. You could use your public IP to forward to your IIS port:

[image]

Here is a sample port forward configuration. It depends on your router:

https://www.lifewire.com/how-to-port-forward-4163829